# How can I call npx cypress open or npx cypress run from in Ubuntu 21.04 terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, cypress

How can I call `npx cypress open` or `npx cypress run` in Ubuntu 21.04 ?

directory location:
\node_modules\cypress\bin

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does the cache folder contain `...cache/Cypress/6.6.0...`?

If not, try to reinstall that specific version, `npm i -D cypress@6.6.0` or `yarn add -D cypress@6.6.0`

According to [Installation - Operating system](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress#Operating-System) you have the right path. Did you clear the cache recently with `cypress cache clear`?